# Choice field data contains # when exported to excel

Tags: excel, export, choice-field

I have a choice field(checkbox, multiple values) in a SharePoint List. In SharePoint values are displayed as Choice1, Choice2.

When exported to Excel the format used in Excel is Choice1,#Choice2

I do not want the # to be present

Comment: I would like to do this inversely. What do I need to type in my Excel file to get a multiple value item in SharePoint when imported from Excel?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/92557)

Answer (score 4):

I am not 100% sure if this should be posted as an answer or a comment (but the question doesn't include a question).

You can't get it without the #. The separator is actually ",#": a comma followed by a pound.

Independently from SharePoint, Excel does handle drop down lists (choice fields), but does NOT handle drop downs with multiple selections. When mapping Excel to SharePoint lists, Microsoft had to find something to show that this was not a standard text field, and they went for this ",#" as just a comma is too common and likely to be present in your values.