# Excel to SharePoint List: How to have a Choice column with multiple values?

Tags: list, excel

I want to do the inverse of [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235397/choice-field-data-contains-when-exported-to-excel/247909#247909).
What do I need to type in my excel field to automatically create a Choice column in SharePoint with multi values when importing the Excel file via the Import Spreadsheet App.

a;#b
and
a,#b

do not work.

Thanks!
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's supported by the import spreadsheet wizard. PowerShell can certainly do this, though that's a bit of a different skill set. Another option that may work for you is documented [here](http://officepowerups.com/2014/04/28/import-to-sharepoint-from-excel/), which involves setting up a workflow to update the multi-value field.